# I am searching to convert complex json to csv using python or R

Tags: python, json, r, csv

It would be helpful if values are converted as rows of CSV and keys are received a columns of CSV.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$uId”: “12345678”
    },
    “comopany_productId”: “J00354”,
    “`company_product name`”: “BIKE 12345”,
    "search_results": [
        {
            “product_id”: "44zIVQ",
            "constituents”: [
                {
                    “tyre”: “2”,
                    "name": “dunlop”
                },
                {
                    "strength": “able to move 100 km”,
                    "name": “MRF”
                }
            ],
            "name": “Yhakohuka”,
            "form": “tyre”,
            "schedule": {
                "category": “a”,
                "label": "It needs a good car to fit in”
            },
            "standardUnits": 20,
            "price": 2000,
            "search_score”:0.947474,
            “Form”: “tyre”,
            "manufacturer": “hum”,
            "id": “12345678”,
            "size": “4”
        },
```

I want uId, company_productId”, "company_product name", various keys in search_results “tyre”,"name",""strength","name","form","schedule","category","label","standard units","price","search_score","Form","manufacturer","id","size" ias difference column in excel and values as rows.

Comment: Please format your header.  I think it is `json` instead of `son`

Comment: Can you give example output that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can use libraries `pandas` and `json` to convert it to a csv like this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

json_normalize(json.loads('your_json_string')).to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

If you have your json saved on a file, use `json.load` instead, passing the `file` object to it.

Comment: Thanks but still getting an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: Mitijans AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta what are you passing to `json.loads`? Or are you using `json.load`?

Comment: Mitijans I am using json.load since i have a file.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Then, you should `open` the file, not passing the filename as a `str`. Here: `json.load(open('file_name.json'))`

Comment: Mitijans thanks but  It is not able to flat search_results keys into different columns and values into different rows.

Comment: Mitijans getting output like this [{u'name': u'Yhakohuka', u'constituents': [{u'tyre': u'2', u'name': u'dunlop'}, {u'strength': u'able to move 100 km', u'name': u'MRF'}], u'name': u'Yhakohuka', u'form': u'tyre', u'schedule': {u'category': u'a', u'label': u'It needs a good car to fit in'}, u'standardUnits': 20, u'price': 2000, u'search_score': 0.947474, u'packageForm': u'Form', u"tyre': u"manufacturer'hum', u'id': u’”12345678, u'size': u’4 tyres’}

Comment: Please, paste your output in your question so we can clearly see what you are expecting.

Comment: I have edited the question according to requirements. Does it help??